# Can't add some phrases in body area in Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Every time I post a question on Stack Overflow and I include greeting phrases like "Hi folks", or just "Hi", etc, etc in the first line or first characters it never appears in the final post. It appears in the preview box, but never in the final result?

I am always logged in using my user account, it does not matter which machine I use, what IP address, etc. I added "Hi folks" in this question and after saving it, it got removed as well.

Why are salutation phrases such as "hi folks" automatically removed from the body of posts?

Comment: I can't tell you why it's automatically rejected, but I agree with this. Salutations (such as *hi folks*, *cheers*  etc) are considered noise on Stack Overflow. SO strives to be a knowledge database, with *Questions, answers, no distractions*. If I have a question, I don't want to be bothered reading through politeness as "Hi folks, how are you doing this fine morning" etc. I just want to read the question and answer.

Comment: There you go; the system does this because you shouldn't post them. Please refrain from adding such things in the future, as they're not supposed to be posted and just result in more work for editors.

Answer (score 9):

> Why are salutation phrases such as "hi folks" automatically removed from the body of posts?

**1) Why - The process**

A [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950) was asked on [meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) and [Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989) implemented it. The community was clearly in favor of removing salutations.

**2) Why - The reasoning**

Stack Exchange sites in general, but also Stack Overflow in particular, are supposed to be repositories of knowledge. There are **questions** and **answers**, and somewhere in between comments for narrow and specific purposes.

It's the *content* that matters and nothing else, especially everything social or personal. Stack Overflow is not a help desk and your posts should be helpful to as many people as possible, not just you. That's why there's no need to say "Hi" or "Thanks" etc.

Even worse, it just distracts from the *content* and adds noise. Imagine looking up something on Wikipedia and the article begins with "Hi, my dear readers!" That's not wanted and not helpful to the developer googling 2 weeks later, who finds your question looking for an answer. They don't want to read pleasantries, they want to know if your problem is relevant to them and how it was solved.